# TypeError: instance.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 

class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props); 
        this.state = { data: null, }; 
    } 

    componentDidMount() { 
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') 
            .then(response => response.json())  
            .then(json => console.log(json)); 
    } 

}

export default App;
```

Comment: In react `render` is the only required method. If you don't have anything to return then do this `render(){return null}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to render something in your component, this means having a `render` method in your class.

Please take a look at the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). and in the [render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) where it says.

> The `render()` method is the only required method in a class component.
> When called, it should examine this.props and this.state and return one of the following types:
>
> - React elements. Typically created via JSX. For example, `<div />` and `<MyComponent />` are React elements that instruct React to render a DOM node, or another user-defined component, respectively.
> - Arrays and fragments. Let you return multiple elements from render. See the documentation on fragments for more details.
> - Portals. Let you render children into a different DOM subtree. See the documentation on portals for more details.
> - String and numbers. These are rendered as text nodes in the DOM.
> - Booleans or null. Render nothing. (Mostly exists to support return test &&  pattern, where test is boolean.)

So making an example with the code from your question

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 

class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props); 
        this.state = { data: null, }; 
    } 

    componentDidMount() { 
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') 
            .then(response => response.json())  
            .then(json => console.log(json)); 
    } 
    
    // added the render method
    render() {
        return (
            // needs to return some of the above listed options
        )
    }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class component you need to render something. for example lets make your code working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props); 
        this.state = { data: null, }; 
    } 

    componentDidMount() { 
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') 
            .then(response => response.json())  
            .then(json => console.log(json)); 
    } 
    public render() {
            return (<div> my component </div>)
    }
}

export default App;
```

here you can see component is rendering a div. I would suggest you can kick start your react learning from [react basic tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) this will help you getting basics before you start working on it. Enjoy react :)